# Regex inside javascript string

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I have a form that needs to be implemented through javascript:

```
var birthdayForm = '<form id="birthday_signup" class="klaviyo_gdpr_embed_Wh3QTB" style="margin-top: 40px;" action="//manage.kmail-lists.com/subscriptions/subscribe" data-ajax-submit="//manage.kmail-lists.com/ajax/subscriptions/subscribe" method="GET" target="_blank" novalidate="novalidate">'+
'<input type="hidden" name="g" value="Wh3QTB">'+
'<input type="hidden" name="$fields" value="Birthday">'+
'<input type="hidden" type="text" name="Birthday" id="final_birthday">'+
'<div class="klaviyo_field_group">'+
'<h2>Vertel ons jouw verjaardag en we zorgen voor een leuke verrassing!</h2>'+
'<input class="" style="display:none;" type="email" value="" name="email" id="k_id_email" placeholder="Your email" />'+
'<div class="klaviyo_field_group klaviyo_form_actions">'+
'<div class="klaviyo_field_group" style="margin: 10px 0;">'+
'<input id="klaviyo_form_Birthday" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\/.]/g, \'\').replace(/(\..*)\./g, \'$1\');" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" maxlength="10" type="text" />'+
'<button type="submit" class="klaviyo_submit_button btn" style="margin-left: 15px;">Versturen</button>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="klaviyo_messages">'+
'<div class="success_message" style="display:none;">'+
'<p class="thank_you">Bedankt om jouw verjaardag te delen!</p>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="error_message" style="display:none;"></div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="klaviyo_form_actions" style="margin: 10px 0;">'+
''+
'</div>'+
'</form>';
```

As you can see, the following regex is beig executed on "oninput":

```
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\/.]/g, \'\').replace(/(\..*)\./g, \'$1\');"
```

Unfortunately, this breaks. It's probably not being escaped correctly. I fail to see how exactly though. Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you put an example of the input you want to make the regex work on and why do you want to make the change oninput

Comment: Updated answer: https://jsfiddle.net/3xyw5g6z/. The oninput change is because i want to help customers to enter their birthday in a correct format. For various reasons, we can't use type=data so i chose type=text instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `type=date`? It would achieve your targets in a much easier way.

Please check my changes here: https://jsfiddle.net/v8cwuq69/3/

I have:

1. changed input type to `date`
2. removed the `oninput` function, I think it's not necessary anymore
3. added `required` boolean property to the `input` element, reason: [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required)
4. I removed your `novalidate` in your `form` node, not sure why you added that though

P.S. I strongly suggest not to write HTML code in JavaScript, but in HTML. It's much easier to maintain, format, and debug.

Comment: Thank you for helping but i'm obligated to use input type text instead of date. So the main question remains: how can i make sure the regular expression is being outputted correctly inside the javascript string. I know it's best not to write html code inside Javascript, but Shopify Checkout only allows for javascript.